# Change Ionic range pin position

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic [range](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/range/Range/) component. By default, if [pin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/range/Range/#input-properties) attribute is set to true in the HTML, a pin with integer value is shown when the knob is pressed. But it appears on top of the knob, like in the below image:

```
<ion-range min="-200" max="200" [(ngModel)]="saturation" color="secondary" pin="true">
```

[image: Ionic range pin]

Is it possible to make it appear **below** the knob? I took a look at the [Sass](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/range/Range/#sass-variables) variables, but I didn't found any useful variable.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found a way inspecting carefully the HTML and looking at the CSS classes. The proper class was `range-pin`, which I accessed like:

```
.range .range-knob-handle .range-pin {
        top: 40px;    // <--- Change this to manually position the pin
        font-size: 14px;    // You can also change other properties
        color: orange;
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

.range .range-knob-handle .range-pin {
top: 40px;    // <--- Change this to manually position the pin
font-size: 14px;    // You can also change other properties
color: orange;
}

if I add this the css is not working.

Comment: What version of Ionic are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Best practice to use Shadow part.

```
ion-range::part(pin) {
  top: 40px;
  transform: none;
}
```

Comment: Only-code or nearly-only-code answers are hard to understand and apply. Can you flesh this answer out, e.g. by adding screenshots, or explaining how the snippet works?